# When to use createSpy, createSpyObject and spyOn?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine2.0

I have learned recently that spyOn cannot be used with external dependencies and can only be used with System Under Test.

But I have some questions regarding why it cant be used and I came up with very few answers.

So I would like to know the best practices where we should use each of them.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/testing shows uses of all three. Best practices are largely opinion based, but mine are: more-or-less exclusively use createSpyObj, for creating test doubles of collaborators; and spying on the SUT is a smell, test behaviours not implementation details.

Comment: I agree with the above.  createSpyObj is the best default.  There are times when I need a more functional mock object though and I've created a simple object which I will then spy on with spyOn.  Similarly with createSpy you may want to use this when you are creating a more functional mock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jasmine.createSpy can be used when there is no function to spy on. It will track calls and arguments like a spyOn but there is no implementation.

jasmine.createSpyObj is used to create a mock that will spy on one or more methods. It returns an object that has a property for each string that is a spy.

you should have a method on the object with spyOn.The advantage of the spyOn is that you can call the original method

Answer (score 2):

We can use **jasmine.createSpy** when we need to spy a function e.g.

```
     let router = { navigate: jasmine.createSpy("navigate") },
```

here we're creating spy function using jasmine.createSpy

**jasmine.createSpyObj** is used to create spy class/obj which has methods e.g.

```
     let service = jasmine.createSpyObj("ApiService", ["getData"])}
```

here ApiService is class which has getData function.